# Beacon delegate methods are not getting triggered when application is in Background state

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process, uilocalnotification, ibeacon

I am working on a beacon Project.

I want to send a local notification on iPhone on beacon detection. That local notification come on device when the application is in Foreground mode but not in background mode. I gave debugged the code, but the issue is when application is in background mode beacon delegate methods are not getting triggered.

I have tried this as a solution but it didn't worked.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [manager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if(CLRegionStateInside==state)
    {

        [region startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
    }
}
```

But these delegate methods are not getting called in background mode.

Please Help me...

Thanks

Comment: did u check location modes option in background Modes ?

Answer (score 0):

Take care when testing in the background that you wait long enough for detections.  Under some circumstances, especially on older devices like the iPhone 4S, **it can take up to 15 minutes to detect in the background**.  See here for details:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html